# How to get Id of a process by port number using Get-Process powershell command

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I need to kill a process which does not list when I use the netstat command. The following command will find the process id of 4 which is not the one that I am looking for.

```
    $processPID =  $($(netstat -aon | findstr '5000')[0] -split '\s+')[-1]
    Stop-Process $processPID
```

I know the process that I need is in the results of the following.

Get-Process -Name dotnet

And I can't find a way to use the Get-Process to use with the port filter. For the information of dotnet people, I am running the project using the dotnet CLI command from powershell.

In the screenshot below, you can see the process id for the process listening on port
5100

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mathias and @Sebastian. With your valuable inputs I came up with the following function to get the process id.

```
    function Get-ProcessByPort {
    param(
        [int]$Port
    )
    $services = netsh http show servicestate
    $positionSession=0
    $countSession=0
    $countProcess=0
    [bool] $takeNextPID=0
    $processId=$null
    foreach ($s in $services){
        if ($takeNextPID -eq 1) {
            $processId=$s
            break
        }
        if ($s -match 'Server session ID') {
            $countSession++
        }
        if ($s -match "HTTP://LOCALHOST:$Port/") {
            $positionSession=$countSession
        }
        if ($s -match 'Process IDs:') {
            $countProcess++
        }
        if ($positionSession -gt 0) {
            if ($countProcess -eq $positionSession) {
                $takeNextPID=1
            }
        }
    }
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($processId)))
    {
        $processId=$processId.Trim()
    }   
    return $processId
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Get-NetTCPConnection` cmdlet to get the same output as netstat, but as structured objects instead of text:

```
Get-NetTCPConnect -LocalPort 5000 |Get-Process -Id {$_.OwningProcess} -IncludeUsername:$false
```

Comment: Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5000 is also returning process id 4. Only Get-Process shows the correct process id.

Comment: @RajeevMenon PID = 4 means it's a kernel-managed listener

Comment: It is weird, I know my .net app is listening on port 5000, not sure how I get the System when I use netstat. By the way, I am invoking a Http.Sys web server while running this application.

Comment: @RajeevMenon You _might_ be able to identity the caller by parsing the output from `netsh http show servicestate`

Comment: Found this comment on some other page. "You should be aware that some services listen on ports though process id 4, SYSTEM.  On this machine IIS is installed and configured to host sites on ports 80, 443, 8080, and 8081. But an IIS service won't show up in your report. " not sure if relevant in my case.

Comment: @RajeevMenon That is most likely what is happening here, yes. You can verify by doing `netsh http show urlacl` - if `http://+5000/` is listed then you know that it's indeed the case

Comment: One (rather disruptive) measure that you could employ here: use `netsh` to remove the URL ACL entry in question, see which process dies :)

Comment: You are correct. I see the app URL in the list when running the netsh command. There are 2 sections in the result. Server Sessions and Request Queues. I think I need to match the http://+5000 in the server sessions section to find the corresponding PID in the Request Queue section. That is a lot of parsing for me. Anyways, I think this is the way to go. If you have any examples of parsing something like the above please provide, else I will try my best my own way. Thank You!!

Comment: @RajeevMenon That sounds like the right approach. I'm afraid I don't know of any existing scripts or tools to parse the servicestate output :-/

Answer (score 1):

As above, here's a function for getting the PID depending if this is either a LocalPort or RemotePort.

```
function Get-ProcessByPort {
    param(
        [int]$Port,
        [ValidateSet('LocalPort', 'RemotePort')]
        [string]$PortType = 'LocalPort'
    )

    $splat = @{
        $PortType = $Port
    }

    $processes = Get-NetTCPConnection @splat | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OwningProcess | ForEach-Object { Get-Process -Id $_ } | Select-Object -Unique
    return $processes | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
}
```

Comment: Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5000 is also returning process id 4. Only Get-Process shows the correct process id.

Comment: What do you feed Get-Process? Can you share a screenshot and mark it?

Comment: Just added a screenshot, hope that is helpful

Comment: I've read the comment chain above and it seems you might need to go with the parsing then as this won't work in this case :/